# Chat room information screen is confusing

Tags: feature-request, chat, design

I wanted to see who the owners were of a certain chat room today, and here's what I saw:

[image]

My first thought was, did I somehow become a room owner without knowing it? Upon more careful consideration, I realized that there are actually 2 columns of users, the left two are room owners, the right two for frequent/current users in the room.

It seems like this could be solved by somehow creating a barrier between the two, maybe putting in some padding or some other such mechanism to indicate separation.

Comment: I'd actually prefer just a list of users (which would be easier to make columns out of, too) and have the big info boxes appear on hover/click.